# How do I set a height with javascript on load

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I set height and visibility (detailsVisible) on load? Thanks in advance.

From here:

[image: from here]

To here:

[image: to here]

Comment: Stop being lazy and paste your text in here.

Comment: Also, if my answer fixed the issue, I'd appreciate if you upvoted and approved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest, and best way to do this is to use a library called jQuery. It allows you to write less code, and provides a lot of pre-written functionality for you.

Firstly, include jQuery in the `<head>` or at the bottom of your `<body>` of your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

Next, you'll want to use this JavaScript. Make sure this is below the `<script>` tag for jQuery, or it won't work:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $theDiv = $('#theid'); // #theid should be the `id` attribute of the div you are trying to modify
    $theDiv.css({'height': '57px'}); // the height can be set to whatever you want
    $theDiv.attr('detailsVisible', true);
});
```

You can also run that particular code which is inside `$(document).ready();` whenever you want, such as when you click on a button etc. This particular code above simply runs as soon as the page is ready.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help mightyspaj

Comment: No worries, if it fixed it can you please mark it as the right answer?